# How to authenticate for specified users only in asp.net mvc

Tags: authentication, asp.net-authorization

I have a method in my controller , let say

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And I have user `email_list`

```
    example-one@gmail.com,example-two@gmail.com,example-three@gmail.com
```

What I want to do is when user redirect to Index() , if user's email included in my `email_list` , I want to give access to this page and if not , I will not give access.
How can I achieved this by checking current user's email inside this method ???

Answer (score 0):

You can create AuthorizeAttribute for ActionResult and from login user session data helps to check the list of emails contains login email or not.

you need to create override method as mention below.

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
                if (filterContext == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext"); }

// Add Email checking code here

base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```